# Replace all table rows with new data from the server using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, socket.io

Am fetching data from server via sockets every 3 mins.
i iterate through data and then mount it under tbody with id="display"
challenge is, new data gets appended to DOM instead of replacing all old data.
I have tried all methods like $('#display').empty().html() and .replaceWith() but still
data gets appended

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Servers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h3>Online Servers</h3>
    </header>
    <section id="work">
        <table class="table" id="sector">
            <thead>
                <th>
                    Location
                </th>
                <th>
                    IP
                </th>
                <th



                    State
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="display">

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </section>
</body>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="sectors.json"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    var socket = io();
    var tab = '';
    var history = [];



    socket.on('update', data => {

        // $.each($('.remote'), function (index, value) {
        //     $(this).remove();
        // });


        data.map((item, index) => {

            //tab += "<p class = 'remote'>" + index + "</p>";
            tab += "<tr><td>" + item.location + "</td><td>" + item.host + "</td><td><div><p>" + item.alive.toString() + "</p><p>" + item.packetLoss + "</p></div></td></tr>"

        })
        $('#display').html(tab);





    })
    socket.on('network', () => {
        console.log("network down")
    })
</script>

</html>
```

// I iterate through the data and mount under tbody but challenge

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Servers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h3>Online Servers</h3>
    </header>
    <section id="work">
        <table class="table" id="sector">
            <thead>
                <th>
                    Location
                </th>
                <th>
                    IP
                </th>
                <th



                    State
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="display">

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </section>
</body>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="sectors.json"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    var socket = io();
    var tab = '';
    var history = [];



    socket.on('update', data => {

        // $.each($('.remote'), function (index, value) {
        //     $(this).remove();
        // });


        data.map((item, index) => {

            //tab += "<p class = 'remote'>" + index + "</p>";
            tab += "<tr><td>" + item.location + "</td><td>" + item.host + "</td><td><div><p>" + item.alive.toString() + "</p><p>" + item.packetLoss + "</p></div></td></tr>"

        })
        $('#display').html(tab);





    })
    socket.on('network', () => {
        console.log("network down")
    })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Where in your code were you adding `$('#display').empty()`?

Comment: I removed it after series of using it and it failed to solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried `$("#display").html('')`?

Comment: yes i did but still, the old rows were not removed